# updating a tuple in a sqlite table in android studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

before voting down please read my question , which I have searched a lot but I couldn't find the answer yet, so I would appreciate if you give me hand to overcome the problem.
Actually I need to update a tuple in a table named "Demographics". But it seems my code does not work correctly, and in fact after running the app , I got the result "0" for updating which means nothing get updated.

```
12-21 12:34:54.190 2351-2367/? D/Update Result:: =0
```

- I guess my problem is due to not pointing to the right row of the table based on Primary key. Actually when a user Register to my app the following things should happen:

1- Create a tuple in "Demographics" table --> username, password and email will be inserted. An auto increment primary key also constructed and inserted.

2- user logins , then he can complete rest of information in "Demographics" table. --> this MODIFICATION is the "update" process which I', asking.

Would you please tell me if the following codes are wrong or have any implicit error?

DemographicsCRUD.java

```
public long UpdateDemographics(Demographics_to demoId) {
    //SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.lastName, demoId.getD_lastName());
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.firstName, demoId.getD_firstName());
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.dateOfBirth, demoId.getD_dateOfBirth())

    long result = database.update(dbHelper.Demographics_Table, values,
            WHERE_ID_EQUALS,
            new String[]{String.valueOf(demoId.getD_patientID())});

    Log.d("Update Result:", "=" + result);
   // db.close();
    return result;
}
```

here is where I call the above code:

```
private void updateDemographicsTable()
{
    ep_demoId = new Demographics_to();
    String ep_na = ep_name.getText().toString();
    String ep_fa = ep_family.getText().toString();
    .
    . 
    .
    ep_demoId.setD_dateOfBirth(ep_bd);
    ep_demoId.setD_firstName(ep_na);
    ep_demoId.setD_lastName(ep_fa);
}

    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        long result = ep_demoCRUD.UpdateDemographics(ep_demoId);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        if (activityWeakRef.get() != null
                && !activityWeakRef.get().isFinishing()) {
            if (result != -1)
                Toast.makeText(activityWeakRef.get(), "Information Updated!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }}
```

Comment: Really not clear what you are asking

Comment: @kuffs ok let me edit my question.

Comment: Is there even data in the table? You have to do an insert before you can update. Otherwise the `where ID = x` bit returns nothing, so nothing is updated

Comment: @cricket_007 yes of course there is, I checked the db, and a user is already there!

Comment: K, hard to know that without seeing an insert statement or the `Demographics_to` class.

Comment: You never set the value of patient_id for `ep_demoId`.

Comment: @cricket_007 :) you're right , thanks. if you mind, you may add this answer and I will mark that as accepted.

Comment: The existing answer already alludes to that issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like whatever you are passing in as the patientID does not have a matching record in the database or the dataobject "Demographics_to" has the patient ID set incorrectly.

Comment: your second idea is what exactly I think. But I don't know how to set it correctly.

Comment: Well you are the only person who could know as it is your code. Nobody else would know how to set a value on a class they haven't written without seeing it.